# JQuery load() function keeps clearing user input

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've got JQuery with a load() function that works every second. However, when I type user input into a search box, it won't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function loadData() {
$('body').load('index.php', function() {
  if(window.reloadData != 0)
    window.clearTimeout(window.reloadData);
    window.reloadData = window.setTimeout(loadData, 1500)
}).fadeIn("slow");
}

window.reloadData = 0;
loadData();

});

<form action="search.php" method="get"><input type="text" placeholder="Search for movie"></form>
```

Comment: You're **replacing** the full body of the page every 1500ms. Why would you expect the input not to be destroyed and recreated per the HTML you're reloading (e.g., without whatever you typed)?

Comment: How would I fix it so the input stays?

Comment: It's going to sound facetious, but: Don't constantly reload the entire page. Reload just a part of it, not including the input.

Comment: It didn't work. It still clears the input. What should I do?

Comment: @SteveWoods did you tried to do like i said in my answer ?

Comment: @edisoni.1337 yes, I have tried. Still doesn't work. Do I have to remove my code I've put in the function? What do I do?

Comment: No simply create a div in your html with id= 'myDiv' and just replace $('body') with $('#myDiv')

Comment: @edisoni.1337 It still doesn't work. I've changed body to #nameofdiv with id. It still clears it.

Comment: Update your question with your new code html and js

Comment: @edisoni.1337 Never mind, I figured it out. I just changed a few things. However, you did help. Thank you.

Comment: If my answer helped you to fix that accept it as correct please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wan't to replace the **entire** body and save the form state, just remove the form and put it back:

```
<!--Index.php-->
<!-- Set a identifier for it -->
<form id="searchForm" <!--more attributes...--> ></form>
```

The Script :

```
///main.js

(($) => {
   const loadData = () => {
      //"take" the form 
      let $form = $('#searchForm').detach();

      $('body').load('index.php', () => {

          if(window.reloadData != 0)
             window.clearTimeout(window.reloadData);

          window.reloadData = window.setTimeout(loadData, 1500);

          //replace the default form with the saved form
          $('#searchForm').replaceWith($form);

        }).fadeIn("slow");
      }
   $(document).ready(() => {

      window.reloadData = 0;
      loadData();

   });
})(jQuery)
```

PS: It's recomended to replace just a div where the search results should appear, because you **don't** want to save the state of every single thing in your page every time :)